# Gettiming "Implicit coercion of a value of type mx.events.FlexEvents to an unrelated type mx.events:ValidationResultEvent

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

In Flex mobile, I am trying to implement a validator for a TextInput field, but the compiler complains about the ValidationResultEvent I pass to the valid event handler:

It complains about this line:

```
<s:TextInput id="expiresIn__" paddingRight="10" valid="expiresInTxt_validHandler(event)" />
```

and for the event param passed to my valid handler, it says:

"Implicit coercion of a value of type mx.events:FlexEvent to an unrelated type mx.events:ValidationResultEvent."

I can't seem to find any answers to how to solve this on the internet. Is there some other way of doing this to make it work?

Comment: I can guess what is going on here (your event is firing one type of event, but your handler is expecting another type), but we need to see the event handler (`expiresInTxt_validHandler`) in order to confirm that.

Comment: In order to avoid this, you can try to put more generic type of event in the handler expiresInTxt_validHandler(evt:Event) so, you can later replace it with the appropriate event type by debuggin it.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler should look something liker this:

```
protected function expiresInTxt_validHandler( e:ValidationResultEvent ):void
{
     // handle it, yo.
}
```

To see the ValidationResultEvent constants, check here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/ValidationResultEvent.html